# How to call a parent method from within a child method?

Tags: javascript, oop, prototypal-inheritance

I have such a code:

```
function A() {
    this.hello = function() {
        console.log("I'm A");
    }
}

function B() {
    this.hello = function() {

        // I need to call A.hello here, like parent.hello();
        B.prototype.hello();   // This is wrong, TypeError

        console.log("I'm B");
    }
}

B.prototype = new A();
var b = new B();

b.hello();
#=> TypeError: Cannot call method 'hello' of undefined
```

I read some similar questions here but they all use this technique, they assign a method to a `prototype`.

```
FaqPage.prototype.init = function(name, faq) {
    BasePage.prototype.init.call(this, name);
    this.faq = faq; 
}
FaqPage.prototype.getFaq = function() {
    return this.faq;
}
```

But it is not in my case. My `prototype` is a parent's instance. How may call a parent method in my case? Or do I have to refactor my code?

Comment: [Simple JavaScript Inheritance](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/)

Comment: As a side note, using `B.prototype = new A();` will execute the constructor of `A` which might not be what you want and could lead to unwanted side-effects. You can use `B.prototype = Object.Create(A.prototype);` to get the same result but the constructor of `A` will **not** be executed. Off course, you then need to make sure `hello` is part of the actual `A.prototype`, See [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wZTy8/)

Answer (score 3):

You need to assign the `this.hello` a value, at the moment you are just creating a function to run.

Try the following :

```
function A() {
    this.hello = function() {
        console.log("I'm A");
    }
}

function B() {
    this.hello = function() {    
        B.prototype.hello();   // Now runs correctly and logs "I'm A"

        console.log("I'm B");
    }
}

B.prototype = new A();
var b = new B();

b.hello();
```

By changing the code to be `this.hello = function() { }` we are creating a property of the object that can be called from outside the object.

The result of calling `b.hello();` is :

```
I'm A
I'm B
```

<kbd>[Example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nunners/5bT8w/1/)</kbd>